# How can I print a table over one page sustaining specific form(part)

Tags: jsp, printing

Hello I'm working in small company in Japan and it's my first time asking a question here.

Before the question, I'd like to apologize for my bad English because English is not my mother language.

ok.

I'm making a print page that contains a long table(vertically) it is showing some kind of stocklist so table's length is not fixed.
May be sometimes it prints 10 kind of stock which means 10 rows of table
or sometimes more than 100 rows.

It's not a problem if it has 10 rows but in case of more than 10 rows I would like to print a 2nd page. 
At that time I want to maintain some page's area(form or image)

---

[present Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zeyx.jpg)

---

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HdX9.jpg)

---

I bring table's Data using Mysql

In this case what should I do?

I tried googling all day but I actually don't know how to search to solve this kind of case.

Thank you for those who read this question and thank you for those who give me any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the [< thead >](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/thead.html) and < tfoot > is used in the < table > structure:

> By explicitly grouping header rows with THEAD, authors give browsers
>   the ability to include the header rows on each page of a printed,
>   multi-page table, as well as the ability to present a long table with
>   a scrolling body and static header rows.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I'm gonna try it!